# Is accessing a table in Postgres 9 any slower if it has extra unused columns?

Tags: performance, postgresql

Imagine I have a table with two columns, a primary key and some data. This table is going to be large and is going to be accessed very frequently.

Now imagine I want to add another piece of data, which is accessed only rarely. Can I safely assume that adding another column to the table is not going to make the common queries any slower if they don’t access the new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory yes: it'll be slower because less rows will fit per disk page. To read table rows, you'll need to visit more pages.

In practice, null values take 1 bit of room, and varlena types are stored in the extended storage (toast). So it makes little material impact.

Comment: I didn’t say the new column is all nulls, or even mostly nulls. In fact it’ll be mostly medium-length text. Does your answer still apply?

Comment: @Timwi: His answer still applies. Medium length text will be stored out-of-line, like a BLOB except transparently to you. Observed speed difference will be essentially zero.